# React Material UI - update TextField based on Slider value but not other way around

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, material-ui, slider

I want to update the value of my TextField based on the value of the slider, but I still want that TextField to be editable for a custom number, if a custom number is entered it overwrites the value in the TextField that comes from the slider but does not update the slider.

I tried setting the TextField as a controlled component and was able to get the value of the slider into it but then could not update it.

I have now grabbed the value of the Slider and the TextField in the same handleChange event, how do I get the TextField to update based on the Slider value but not vice versa?

```
    export default function App() {
  
    var sliderVal
    var textFieldVal 
    const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
    
     if (newValue === undefined) {
          sliderVal = sliderVal;
        } else sliderVal = newValue
    
     if (event.target.value === undefined) {
          textFieldVal = textFieldVal
        } else textFieldVal = event.target.value
    
     };
      const marks = [
        {
          value: 20,
          label: "20 +"
        },
        {
          value: 200,
          label: "200 +"
        }
      ];
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <Slider
            defaultValue={20}
            valueLabelDisplay="auto"
            step={10}
            marks={marks}
            min={20}
            max={200}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
    
          <TextField
            name="yearlyDelay"
            variant="outlined"
            id="yearlyDelay"
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
        </div>
      );

   }
```

I have attached a workable example on codesandbox here - [Working Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-elbakyan-3ngf8?file=/src/App.js:165-947)
(Pardon the styling I just threw it together)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a state value that you can use as textbox value.

Here is the working code.

```
export default function App() {
  const [val, setVal] = useState(20);
  const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
    const sliderVal = newValue;
    const textFieldVal = event.target.value;
    setVal(newValue); 
  };
  const marks = [
    {
      value: 20,
      label: "20 +"
    },
    {
      value: 200,
      label: "200 +"
    }
  ];
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Slider
        defaultValue={20}
        valueLabelDisplay="auto"
        step={10}
        marks={marks}
        min={20}
        max={200}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />

      <TextField
        name="yearlyDelay"
        variant="outlined"
        id="yearlyDelay"
        value={val}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
    </div>
  );
```

}